# How would I give the <button>'s I created from my array their own individual ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a div in my html file that has a id="buttons" and I target that to append my array of buttons. That works. How would I then give every button using jquery an id so I can target it individually?

For overall project context what I'm trying to do is make buttons using an array. Then using those buttons I will be able to display gifs that correspond with button clicked. i.e. Click baseball and 20 baseball gifs show up on the page.

```
var topics = ["baseball", "hockey", "football", "basketball", "soccer", 
"volleyball", "softball", "handball", "pickleball", "tennis"];

var queryURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + topics[0] + 
"&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=20";

$(document).ready(function(){
for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++){
    var buttons = topics;
    $("#buttons").append("<button>" +buttons[i]+ "</button>");

$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
}).done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.data[0].url)

});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign random ID or you can use your button name as ID to set it UNIQUE

```
$("#buttons").append("<button id="+buttons[i]+">" +buttons[i]+ "</button>");
```

or

```
$("#buttons").append("<button id="+buttons[i]+"_"+i+">" +buttons[i]+ "</button>");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

Basicly you use your iterator to make the id's different:

```
var topics = ["baseball", "hockey", "football", "basketball", "soccer", 
"volleyball", "softball", "handball", "pickleball", "tennis"];

var queryURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + topics[0] + 
"&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=20";

$(document).ready(function(){
for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++){
    var buttons = topics;
    $("#buttons").append('<button id="topic_button_' + i + '">' +buttons[i]+ "</button>");

$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
}).done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.data[0].url)

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the id inside the `append` function:

```
append ("<button id='" + buttons[i] + "'>" + buttons [i] + "</button>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var topics = ["baseball", "hockey", "football", "basketball", "soccer", 
  "volleyball", "softball", "handball", "pickleball", "tennis"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  // for every topic, append a button under #buttons
  // save the topic name within the button, as data-topic attribute, for later use
  for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    $("#buttons").append('<button data-topic="' + topics[i] + '">' + topics[i] + '</button>');
  }
  
  // click handler for buttons
  $('#buttons > button').on('click', function() {
    // time to use the saved topic from data-topics
    var topic = $(this).data('topic');
    // construct the url for this specific topic
    var queryURL = "http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + topic +
                   "&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=20";
    
    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    }).done(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.data[0].url)
  });
});
```